# Spring Security OAuth2- POST request to oauth/token redirects to login and role displays ROLE_ANONYMOUS

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am following the link https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v & the github project https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2. I am able to login in to the OAuth provider and get the authorization code back in the client.

Now I make the following call from the client to get the token from the provider (provider is on port 9999)

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        List<String> cookies = httpEntity.getHeaders().get("Cookie");
        headers.put("Cookie", cookies);
        String redirectURL= "http://localhost:9999/oauthprovider/oauth/token" +  "?" + "response_type=token" + "&" + "grant_type=authorization_code" + "&" + "client_id=acme"+ "&" + "client_secret=acmesecret"+  "&" + "redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/callback"+"&" + "code=" + authCode + "&" + "state=" + stateValue;

        HttpEntity<String> redirectResponse = template.exchange(
                redirectURL,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    responseentity,
                    String.class);


        result=redirectResponse.toString()
```

The result variable value has the following.(I have disabled csrf and sending client_secret as a query parameter (for the time being), although they are not recommended)

```
    <302 Found,{X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Location=[http://localhost:9999/oauthprovider/oauthlogin], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Thu, 09 Nov 2017 12:07:37 GMT]}>
```

In the console I have these

```
   Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 2B669DF59BCE8047849BFBCA148BEE67; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

Does I am redirecting back to login(I am getting it in the logs as mentioned before), since the role is ROLE_ANONYMOUS? How can I fix the issue?

Adding more details on the code (Did only minor changes from the sample code provided in the link). Providers's context path is /oauthprovider and with curl call I am getting the token.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    //................................
    //................................
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme")
                .secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                        "password").scopes("openid").autoApprove(true).redirectUris("http://localhost:8081/callback"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(
                jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                "isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/oauthlogin").loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll() 
        .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauthlogin", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token" ,"/oauth/confirm_access")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I do not follow you clearly. In which format I should send  client_id and client_secret? I have added the following headers.add("Authentication","acme:acmesecret"); in the redirect call to oauth/token. But the result was same The authorization redirect call was automatically happening since I used @EnableOAuth2SSO

Comment: See [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html).

Comment: And AFAIK: the redirect has nothing to do with `@EnableOAuth2SSO`, it is part of your authentication server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For calling token endpoint you need to send `Authorization` header with value `base64(client_id:client_secret)` and in body you should  send `username` , `password` ,`grant_type` as `FORM_URLENCODED`:

```
      String oauthHost = InetAddress.getByName(OAUTH_HOST).getHostAddress();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        // Basic Auth
        String plainCreds = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        // params
        map.add("username", username);
        map.add("password", password);
        map.add("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map,
                headers);
        // CALLING TOKEN URL
        OauthTokenRespone res = null;
        try {
            res = restTemplate.postForObject(OAUTH_TOKEN_URL.replace(OAUTH_HOST, oauthHost), request,
                    OauthTokenRespone.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class OauthTokenRespone {
        private String access_token;
        private String token_type;
        private String refresh_token;
        private String expires_in;
        private String scope;
        private String organization;
        //getter and  setter
}
```

Comment: Also you can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159978/share-spring-security-context-between-two-applications/47182121#47182121

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I read and wrote too fast. The problem was *and in body you should send username , password ,grant_type*. That's not neccessary, you can also use query parameters. Both are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong in my last day's testing. I can get access token if my handler is either in client or in provider. If my redirect handler is in provider the user is not anonymous as per the debug logs (may be due to session..?)But looks like I have to use one redirect_url consistently.(Otherwise I get redirect_uri mismatch error..)

Following is the working code that gets json response..

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/clientcallback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<OauthTokenResponse> redirectCallback(@RequestParam (value= "code", defaultValue="") String authCode,@RequestParam (value= "state", defaultValue="") String stateValue,HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) 
{

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    String plainCreds = "acme:acmesecret";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

        List<String> cookies = httpEntity.getHeaders().get("Cookie");
        if(cookies != null)
        {
            headers.put("Cookie", cookies);
        }
        else
        {

            cookies = httpEntity.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
            headers.put("Set-Cookie", cookies);
        }
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map,
                headers);

        OauthTokenResponse res = null;
        try {
            res = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/clientcallback&code=" + authCode, request,    
                    OauthTokenResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  new ResponseEntity<OauthTokenResponse>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Thanks again for the tips..

Comment: A token endpoint accepts HTTP POST requests with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This means request parameters to a token endpoint must be embedded in the request body. However, you place request parameters in the query component part. That is, the URL given to postForObject() contains `"?grant_type=..."`, but it's wrong. See "1.3. Request To Token Endpoint" in [Diagrams And Movies Of All The OAuth 2.0 Flows](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've recently faced a very similar issue so I'm posting my solution.

I used [Simle SSO Example](https://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2) as a base for my modifications. I'm using spring security filter which is mapped to `/` (web root) and spring oauth with endpoints mapped to `/auth/*`. When I try to access `/auth/oauth/token` I get redirect to login page. After some debugging I found out the cause:

By using `@EnableAuthorizationServer` you are importing `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` which secures endpoints `/oauth/token`, `/oauth/token_key` and `/oauth/check_token`. Everything is going to work with this default configuration as long as your authorization server is mapped to the web root. In my case, requests to `/auth/oauth/token` were simply redirected to login page because spring security could not find a rule for this path.

My solution was to manualy secure those endpoints with `/auth` prefix in my spring security configuration.

Hope this helps.